# Force encoded period in API request

Tags: python-requests

I'm attempting to consume a REST API that does not handle periods correctly.

It will fail on http://api.com/endpoint?myparameter=includes%20a.

But it works fine when the period is encoded as %2E thus:

http://api.com/endpoint?myparameter=includes%20a%2E

Works fine.

Try as I might, when using requests the %2E always seems to get converted back into a "."

Is there any way of avoiding this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Prepared Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) to get this to work since Requests by default will use the `requote_uri(uri)` function in `requests.util` to helpfully take care of unquoting the unreserved characters for you. If you already have parsed and prepped the URL yourself, you can do the following and override the `url` field:

```python
from requests import Session, Request

s = Session()

req = Request('GET', 'http://localhost:8008?name=kevin%2Eemckinsey')

# This will use `requote_uri` to unquote unreserved characters so %2E becomes a `.`
prepped = req.prepare()

# Forcing the `url` field to be a URL we specified.
prepped.url = 'http://localhost:8008?name=kevin%2Emckinsey'

resp = s.send(prepped)

print(resp.url)
print(resp.json())

# http://localhost:8008?name=kevin%2Emckinsey
# PHP's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns:
# {'name': '/?name=kevin%2Emckinsey'}
```

This seems like a dirty trick to me but AFAIK, there's no way to tell Requests not to unquote a specific character.

Comment: Thanks! That did indeed get around the problem.